# Coordinates of a point when it is known the distance and the coordinates of another point

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know the coordinates of a point $A = (55.0001, 32.6789)$ and I know that the distance from another point is $d=10$ meters. How can I find the coordinates of the other point?

Comment: You can not, you can only say that this other point is located on the circle of center $A$ and radius $d$.

Comment: As you know, the points that are a fixed distance away from a center point, form a circle. Therefore, the conditions that you have said so far, form a circle. In order to reduce the the number of solutions to one, we would need more conditions.

Comment: I also know that the angle is formed between these two points is 90 degrees.

Comment: An angle requires three points. Is the vertex the origin? That narrows it down to two possibilities.

Comment: it is the origin.

Comment: The tangents through the origin to the circle of radius 10 centered at $A$ form much less than a 90-degree angle, so there is no such point. This 90 degrees that you mention must not be measured with respect to the origin, so exactly what do you mean by this angle?

Answer (score 0):

That would be any point that satisfies the equation $$\sqrt{ \left(x-55.0001\right)^2+\left(y-32.6789\right)^2}=10$$

Comment: Yes, but I want to find x,y. How can I do that?

Comment: There is not just one pair $(x,y)$ which satisfies that equation

Comment: Another way to write these solutions is
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x &=& 55.0001 + 10\cos{\theta}\\
y &=& 32.6789 + 10\sin{\theta}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for any real value of $\theta$.

Comment: If we consider that θ = 90 ° the coordinates (x,y) may have as a result (55.0001, 42.6789). The result of the coordinates is unreal about the actual data.